# Understanding Energy Meter Output

Tags: power, plug, meter

I am not an electrical engineer. I am software engineer trying to build an app to work with a smart plug and I just don't understand the basic concepts and so just looking for some beginner help.

I want the app to be able to tell the user how much electricity he has been using for say the last hour. I understand that what is relevant here is power (voltage * current) and that the unit is kW.
The smart plug sends voltage and current (and power) measurements every second.

Can I simply sum up the power used in each second for the last hour to get power used for the total hour? Is that going to be wildly inaccurate? Like, electricity usage is a continuous quantity and I'm getting discrete measurements of usage for a second so I am going to be badly off?

Answer (score 0):

> *I understand that what is relevant here is power (voltage * current)
> and that the unit is kw*

The basic unit is the "watt" (W) but, for electrical energy usage, the kW is usually the preferred unit of power. And, if you consume an average of 1 kW for 1 hour, that becomes an energy of 1 kWh.

However, power is instantaneous voltage multiplied by instantaneous current i.e. it is a snap-shot value and, it needs to be averaged so, at the working heart of a power meter is something that does an "instantaneous" power calculation in a tiny fraction of a second.

> *Can I simply sum up the power used in each second for the last hour to
> get power used for the total hour?*

Yes you can and its units will be in watt-hours. If you get 1000 watt-hours accumulated then, that is 1 kWh (a standard unit for energy consumption).

In other words, energy is power multiplied by time.

> *Is that going to be wildly inaccurate?*

Digitally adding numbers together is not known to have inaccuracies providing you don't overrun your storage memory with a number that is too big. Any inaccuracies is down to the thing that measures power and presents you with a possibly inaccurate number every second.

> *Like, electricity usage is a continuous quantity and I'm getting
> discrete measurements of usage for a second*

If you get a reading of power every second that is equivalent to watt-seconds.

---

**Added details about power measurement as requested by the OP (taken from comments)**

> *I more trying understand, for example when an electricity supplier
> sends you your power bill, how are they doing the measurement of total
> power that you used over a month*

When you measure power over a certain timespan and produce a "power_number" at the end of that timespan, that number must be the average power over that timespan. In other words, sampling power can produce big errors if you don't know what you are doing and under-sample.

> *and how accurate is it?*

I can't tell you how accurate a particular power meter is; I'd have to read the product data sheet.

> *If they measure your power usage every second for a month and sum it,
> then are they missing power used between those every-second
> measurements? Similarly, if I only record power usage of my plug once
> a second, than am I going to miss usage between the second intervals?*

So, to calculate power you should sample voltage and current at fairly high-speed and average over the time span in which energy numbers are to be transferred. If once per second, then you average the instantaneous values of power over 1 second. But, you power calculation time might be 0.1 ms to 1 ms so, you would need to average 1000 to 10,000 numbers to get the average power.

Not calculating power quickly enough can lead to poor accuracy. Gaps can lead to inaccuracies.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I more trying understand, for example when an electricity supplier sends you your power bill, how are they doing the measurement of total power that you used over a month and how accurate is it? If they measure your power usage every second for a month and sum it, then are they missing power used between those  every-second measurements? Similarly, if I only record power usage of my plug once a second, than am I going to miss usage between the second intervals?

Comment: @MosheW I've added details to my answer but, bear in mind that this isn't a forum however, because you are a newbie I will make an exception this time.

Answer (score 0):

Power is instantaneous.  I can be using 5000W now and 50 watts a second later.

The unit you are looking for is watt hours.  That is energy, not power.  The power company bills you for energy, not power.

You are getting readings that give you the average power over the last second.  If you add up all the power readings in one hour, you will get the energy used in watt seconds.  Divide that by 3600 to get watt hours.  Divide by 1000 to get kilowatt hours.  The bill from the power company is usually calculated from kilowatt hours of energy.

---

Adding up the energy usage per second should be as accurate as what the power company puts on the bill.

Appliances don't usually change their energy consumption greatly with in one second.  They also don't switch on and off all that often.

If you turn off a 5000 watt appliance, then there will be a worst case of 5000 watt seconds inaccuracy (assuming that the power meter continues to show 5000 watts for one second after the device was turned off.)  That's 1.4 watt hours, or 0.0014 kilowatt hours.  You'd have to encounter that (maximally bad) situation 720 times before it would add up to one kilowatt hour of inaccuracy.

Most devices don't use that much power and most devices aren't turned on and off 720 times in a month.

Simply adding up the power usage in watts for each second then dividing by 3600 then by 1000 should be more than adequate to get a good number of kilowatt hours.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "power used for the total hour" since power is a momentary measure.  You can calculate average power, and you can calculate *energy* used for the total hour.

If your measurement is really momentary, integrating the power continuously over a stretch of time for an AC device (some of the momentary power may be negative if your "power factor" is not 1) will give the effective energy as metered by power meters, in W s or W hr.  If you only get an *AC* reading, that already is a kind of average (RMS) for current and voltage independently.  The product reflects the apparent power (measured in VA) that needs to be supported by your wiring (the wiring actually doesn't care about the voltage, just the current).

There is also effective power as a shortterm average (over a whole number of AC cycles) of the momentary power, measured in Watts.

A "smart plug" more likely than not already sends AC averages.  Sufficient smartness would send RMS values for voltage and current (allowing you to determine apparent power) and shortterm integrals of momentary power (corresponding to effective power).

The RMS values and effective power info should be comparatively accurate when voltage and current are sinoidal and stable.  If they aren't, accuracy depends on the quality of the smart plug.